# Tab key issue in FireFox

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using following jquery code to allow only alphabetic,-,' but tab key is not working in FireFox-

```
$('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) {
    var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-']/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 45 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
$('.regx').on("paste",function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can anyone resolve this?